# Solving differential equation $y'' + a^2y = f''(x)$ using Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I need to solve this differential equation using these conditions with the help of Laplace transform, but I am stuck. This question is from methods for solving differential equations. I am familiar on how to do Laplace transformations to an extent, however I am not sure how to apply it to the differential equation in question.

$$y'' + a^2y = f''(x);\quad \cases{y(0) = f(0)\cr y'(0) = f'(0)}$$

Here is my attempt:
We start by getting individual Laplace transforms of each one.

$\mathcal{L}\{y''\} = s^2Y(s) - sy(0) - y'(0)=s^2Y(s) - sf(0) - f'(0)$

$\mathcal{L}\{a^2y\} = a^2Y(s)$

$\mathcal{L}\{f''(x)\} = s^2 F(s) - sf(0) - f'(0).$

$$Y(s)=\frac{s^2}{s^2+a^2}F(s)$$
Then we try taking inverses and get

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{Y(s)\}=s\cdot \frac{s}{s^2+a^2}\cdot F(s)=\delta'(t)*\text{cos}(at)*f(t)?$$

This is where I am stuck. By the way, are my calculations correct, because I highly doubt they are? How do I move further?

Comment: Looks fine. Now isolate Y and get its inverse. It looks like you will need to use the shift theorems and possibly write some part(s) of the inverse as convolution(s). I haven't gone through it though.

Comment: @Paul I made some progress, is this correct, how do I move further?

Comment: Now use $\delta'*u*v=u'*v=u*v'$. But be aware of the cutoff at zero, so actually $u(t)=\Theta(t)\cos(at)$, $v(t)=\Theta(t)f(t)$ etc. Or use the "Laplace convolution" and check how partial integration works there.

Comment: $\frac{s^2}{s^2+a^2}=1-\frac{a^2}{s^2+a^2}=1-a\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}$  and as said earlier, remember that a product in the s domain transforms to a convolution in the t doamin.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Am I correct in interpreting that by first formula I get $\text{cos}^{'}(at)*f(t)=\cos(at)*f'(t)$? What is $\operatorname{\Theta}(t)$ here?

Comment: $\Theta$ is here for my purposes the Heaviside function, that is, the unit jump at zero. In the Laplace transform, convolution has the form $\int_0^tu(t-s)v(s)ds$, while the general convolution has all of $\Bbb R$ as integration interval.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Alright, then is this correct approach: $(\Theta(t)\cos(at))^{'}*(\Theta(t)f(t))=(\Theta(t)\cos(at))*(\Theta(t)f(t))^{'}$? Or am I still misunderstanding something over here. How to move forward from this one, I don't know the convulation of these equations?

Comment: The approach suggested by @Paul is much simpler than the one you are trying to follow.

Comment: @Gonçalo I still get this $\delta(t)-a\sin(at)*F(t)$, still don't know how to do it.

Comment: There is no $\delta(t)$. 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{Y(s)\}&=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{\frac{s^2}{s^2+a^2}F(s)\right\}
=\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left\{F(s)-\frac{a^2}{s^2+a^2}F(s)\right\} \\
&=f(t)-a\sin(at)*f(t)=f(t)-a\int_0^{t}\sin(a(t-s))f(s)\,ds.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:
\begin{align}
y''(t) + a^2 \, y(t) &= f''(t) \\
y'(0) &= f'(0) \\
y(0) &= f(0)
\end{align}
and the modern standard Laplace transform
$$ f(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-s t} \, f(t) \, dt \quad \text{ or } \quad f(t) \doteqdot f(s) $$
then the follow can be determined.

Let $f''(t) = p(t)$, which for now is some function, then
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{ y'' + a^2 \, y \} &= \mathcal{L}\{ p(t) \} \\
s^2 \, y(s) - y'(0) - s \, y(0) + a^2 \, y(s) &= p(s) \\
(s^2 + a^2) \, y(s) &= p(s) + y'(0) + s \, y(0) \\
y(s) &= \frac{p(s)}{s^2 + a^2} + \frac{y'(0)}{s^2 + a^2} + \frac{y(0) \, s}{s^2 + a^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{a} \, p(s) \, \frac{a}{s^2 + a^2} + \frac{y'(0)}{a} \, \frac{a}{s^2 + a^2} + y(0) \, \frac{s}{s^2 + a^2}. 
\end{align}
The inverse of this result is
$$ y(t) = \frac{1}{a} \, \int_{0}^{t} p(u) \, \sin(a(t-u)) \, du + \frac{y'(0)}{a} \, \sin(a t) + y(0) \, \cos(a t). $$

Now, returning to $p(t) = f''(t)$ leads to
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{t} p(u) \, \sin(a(t-u)) \, du \\
&= \int_{0}^{t} f''(u) \, \sin(a(t-u)) \, du \\
&= a \, f(t) - f'(0) \, \sin(a t) - a \, f(0) \, \cos(a t) - a^2 \, \int_{0}^{t} f(u) \, \sin(a(t-u)) \, du
\end{align}
which gives $y(t)$ as:
\begin{align}
y(t) &= f(t) + \frac{y'(0) - f'(0)}{a} \, \sin(a t) + (y(0) - f(0)) \, \cos(a t) \\
& \hspace{15mm} -  a \, \int_{0}^{t} f(u) \, \sin(a(t-u)) \, du.
\end{align}
Using $y'(0) = f'(0)$ and $y(0) = f(0)$ reduces the result to
$$ y(t) = f(t) - a \, \int_{0}^{t} f(u) \, \sin(a(t-u)) \, du. $$

**Notes:**

The problem proposer has obtained the result
$$ Y(s) = \frac{s^2 \, F(s)}{s^2 + a^2}. $$
In the method shown to obtain this result the conditions given were already used. What is left is just to determine the inverse of the transform. This can be done by considering:
\begin{align}
Y(s) &= \frac{s^2 \, F(s)}{s^2 + a^2} \\
&= \left( 1 - \frac{a^2}{s^2 + a^2} \right) \, F(s) \\
&= F(s) - a \, \frac{a}{s^2 + a^2} \, F(s)
\end{align}
which has the inverse
$$ y(t) = f(t) - a \, \int_{0}^{t} \sin(a(t-u)) \, f(u) \, du. $$

This gives the same result in both demonstrations (the proposer's work by using the conditions first and the solution presented which uses the conditions last).

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(t):=\cos(at)*f(t)$; then, following your approach, we have
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{Y(s)\}&=\delta'(t)*g(t) \phantom{\int_0^t}\\
&=\int_0^t\delta'(t-s)g(s)\,ds \\
&=\int_0^{t}\delta'(\tau)g(t-\tau)\,d\tau \\
&=-\frac{d}{d\tau}g(t-\tau)|_{\tau=0} \\
&=\frac{d}{dt}g(t-\tau)|_{\tau=0} \\
&=\frac{d}{dt}g(t) \\
&=\frac{d}{dt}[\cos(at)*f(t)] \\
&=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t\cos(a(t-s))f(s)\,ds \\
&=\cos(a(t-t))f(t)+\int_0^t\frac{d}{dt}\cos(a(t-s))f(s)\,ds \\
&=f(t)-a\int_0^t\sin(a(t-s))f(s)\,ds. 
\end{align}
It's the same result obtained using the (much simpler) approach suggested by Paul.